# Does the HPE ML350 support 970 Pro?

Tags: nvme, hpe

I am going in for an IO intensive application and have though of HPE ML350 for the purpose. I need to know if the NVMe SSDs are supported as boot drivers or not. Also if the drives are supported inherently supported or do I need to have any upgrade kits installed?
I have already gone through the HP documentation and its pretty vague.

Thank you

Comment: *Which generation* of ML350 are you talking about? Assuming that you're talking about ML350 **Gen10**, you'll need the appropriate NVMe drive cage and the associated PCIe riser boards (because NVMe's point is that it plugs directly onto the PCIe bus rather than to a SAS/SATA controller). As far as I know, the drive cage kit is `HPE ML350 Gen10 NVMe 8SFF Exp Bay Kit (874569-B21)` and it will have the additional requirement of `HPE ML350 Gen10 Redundant Fan Cage Kit (874572-B21)`. The cage kit includes 2 riser boards: with just one, you can fit up to 4 NVMe SSDs; with 2 you get the maximum 8.

Comment: Thanks a lot!, Yes I am talking about Gen 10